# using jquery to remove links, but not images

Tags: jquery

I have a  that has a bunch of list items, each with an image wrapped in a hyperlink. I'm trying to write some jQuery that will remove the links, but not the images. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you aren't running 1.4:

```
$("a:has(img)").each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).children()); })
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried running 1.4, but I kept getting odd errors with jquery.ui.tabs that loaded via ajax - and I don't have time to change everything, so I can't use 1.4 for this project.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery 1.4, you could try

```
$('#list').find('img').unwrap();
```

Assuming all images in that list are all wrapped in a hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

`href` is an attribute, so in your selector you can do something like:

```
$('img', 'a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href','');
});
```