# How to remove image links in Blogger blog?

Tags: image, hyperlink, blogs, blogger

I am quite new to blogs. I found out that images in my blog has links(with .jpg extensions).
I want it to be removed. Its blogger blog. Is that possible?
Here is URL- http://kripalgamer.blogspot.com/

Comment: Removing the anchor tag but keeping the image inside the anchor tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104607/using-jquery-to-remove-links-but-not-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a image in your blogger post the image is automatically wrapped inside an anchor tag to the original image file. That's the reason images you post on bloggers are clickable, if you remove the anchor tag, the image becomes unclickable.To do so

Open your blogger post editor, upload an image in a blank post and then switch to the HTML mode (use the buttons on top left). This is what you will see :

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">

<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UnwdX_4lJzU/UR28aE-ezxI/AAAAAAAACbc/
   uIBMyGeVf-g/s1600/301804_419266174773556_195336197166556_1276547_111
   7941733_n.jpg" imageanchor="1"   style="margin-left: 1em; 
   margin-right: 1em;">

 <img border="0" height="320" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UnwdX_4lJzU/
    UR28aEezxI/AAAAAAAACbc/uIBMyGeVfg/s320/301804_419266174773556_
    195336197166556_1276547_1117941733_n.jpg" width="286" />
```

delete first and fourth line but the problem is you have to do with every individual image

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RemlinkJS. Using RemlinkJS will enable you to remove the hyperlink from the blog post images, either all of the image or just some specific images. To get the RemlinkJS and the how-to, you can follow this link https://writingnblogging.blogspot.com/2021/07/removing-hyperlinks-from-post-image.html
Edit:
This is how you use the RemlinkJS

1. Get the JS code from the link above;
2. Copy, replace the divClass from remlink to separator if you want to disable hyperlink from all uploaded images, or let it just how it is if you want to disable hyperlink from specific images;
3. Paste the RemlinkJS code to your blogger HTML template just before the  tag and save it;
4. Assume that you want to disable just some of them, go to the blog post that you want to disable the image hyperlink of;
5. Locate the image code in the HTML editor (find <div class = "separator"..>);
6. Add remlink as the value of the class after the separator so it will be like <div class = "separator remlink"...>;
7. Save or update.